# how to align html5 video tag and image tag

Tags: css

I tried to align the html video tag and image in html table. But did not succeeded. Seems like video tag align more bottom instead of top.

Picture is attached how its look.

Css

```
.newsImage {
    width: 354px;
    height: 204px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[image]

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="auto-style1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="height: 80px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <h2>NYHETER</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="newsImage">
            <span id="Content_lbImageNews1"><video width="354" height="240" controls="controls" preload="metadata"><source src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/11332241297A-v5.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></span>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="newsImage">
            <span id="Content_lbImageNews2"><a href="newsDetail.aspx?newsID=19"><img src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/1142145490news3.png" Height="204" Width="354"></a></span>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="newsImage">
            <span id="Content_lbImageNews3"><a href="newsDetail.aspx?newsID=27"><img src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/279096911logga.jpg" Height="204" Width="354"></a></span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inline height value you set it to be 240 instead of 204 which matches your other elements:

```
<video width="354" height="240" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
```

Change that back and you should have to mess with any other code.

```css
.newsImage {
  min-width: 354px;
  min-height: 204px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="auto-style1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="height: 80px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <h2>NYHETER</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="newsImage">
            <span id="Content_lbImageNews1"><video width="354" height="204" controls="controls" preload="metadata"><source src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/11332241297A-v5.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></span>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="newsImage">
            <span id="Content_lbImageNews2"><a href="newsDetail.aspx?newsID=19"><img src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/1142145490news3.png" Height="204" Width="354"></a></span>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="newsImage">
            <span id="Content_lbImageNews3"><a href="newsDetail.aspx?newsID=27"><img src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/279096911logga.jpg" Height="204" Width="354"></a></span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my images are fix so i want to fix video as well, with 100% video goes bigger then images which look not consistent.

Comment: I found an answer I missed yesterday. I edited my answer and hope it helps.

Comment: I also found my type mistake in my original html video tag height is set to 240 instead of 204. after fix this type its look fine

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this to the css file

```
.newsImage {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
.newsImage {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<html>
</html>

<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="auto-style1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="height: 80px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <h2>NYHETER</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="newsImage">
      <span id="Content_lbImageNews1"><div class="videoWrapper"><video width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls" preload="metadata"><source src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/11332241297A-v5.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></div></span>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="newsImage">
      <span id="Content_lbImageNews2"><a href="newsDetail.aspx?newsID=19"><img src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/1142145490news3.png" Height="204" Width="354"></a></span>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="newsImage">
      <span id="Content_lbImageNews3"><a href="newsDetail.aspx?newsID=27"><img src="https://bokning.7a.se/Media/newsImages/279096911logga.jpg" Height="204" Width="354"></a></span>
  </tr>
</table>
</body
```

Comment: As you see my class have vertical align set to top as well